# Timeline Control

Tags: windows, library, .net

I'm searching for a Timeline Control for WPF technologies.
It must show days of the month as a timeline, like these photos:
[image]
[image]

**The Control should be:**

- free
- .Net WPF Compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this control, It's called Timeline:
http://timeline.codeplex.com/

It's WPF/Silverlight compatible, and open source.